# How can I stop GNU screen killing my terminals on remote detach?

Tags: gnu-screen

When I start screen in one terminal with

```
$ screen -R foo
```

and then remotely power-detach from another terminal with

```
$ screen -D foo
```

my first terminal dies. (Meaning, if I run it from gnome-terminal, the whole gnome-terminal window disappears.)

Is there a way to change this behavior so I can continue to use the original terminal after screen dies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution is not to use "power detach", but just a "normal detach"; the behaviour you're trying to avoid is exactly the difference between the two.

Instead of `screen -D` use `screen -d`, note lower case.

Comment: Oh, wow… I guess I thought "power detach" would make it less polite, not more destructive. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if there's not a proper solution, I found a workaround. If you start the original screen session with:

```
$ $SHELL
$ screen -R foo
```

so you're running screen in a shell within a shell, then when it gets remotely detached and tries to kill your shell, it just kills the inner shell and returns you to the outer, original shell.